# "TypeError: User is not a constructor " while sending object to server in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to save a user to mongodb database using post request as follow, but I got the error TypeError: User is not a constructor. It's a pretty simple set up of the code but i can't figure out anything wrong with it.

```
//models/users.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const confic = require('../models/users');

// User schema
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
          type: String,
         },
     email: {
          type: String,
          required: true
         },
    username:{
          type: String,
          required: true
         },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
   });

 const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

   module.exports.getUserById = function(id,callback){
    User.findById(id,callback);
   }

  module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username,callback){
    const query = {username:username}
    User.findOne(query,callback);
  }

 module.exports.addUser= function (newUser, callback) {
   bcrypt.gensalt(10,(err,salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt , (err, hash) =>{
       if(err) throw err;
       newUser.password=hash;
       newUser.save(callback);
     });
   });
}
```

**routes/users.js**

```
 //routes/users.js

 const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();
 const passport = require('passport');
 const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
 User = require('../models/users');

  // // Register
  router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    var newUser = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  User.addUser(newUser, (err, User) => {
    if(err){
      res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to register user'});
     } else {
      res.json({success: true, msg:'User registered'});
    } 

 });

});

  // Authenticate
 router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
 res.send('AUTHENTICATE');
 });

  // Profile
 router.get('/profile', (req, res, next) => {
 res.send('PROFILE');
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

I am using Postman chrome to send data but it is not showing user registered according to program. [image]

Comment: Should not `User = require('../config/database')` be `User = require('../models./users')` or is is actually meant to be re-exported from another file you did not include? At any rate `User` is not being defined as the model that you think it is. Also you should see server error logs, which are more informative to post than pictures of your browser. Exactly why there is a reputation cap here on posting images. Because we really don't need them.

Comment: "TypeError: bcrypt.gensalt is not a function" yes but now it showing this error

Comment: We can't debug your whole application, and especially since you're not even listing or pointing out where the errors are actually occurring, which as I pointed out are logged elsewhere. Look at that log. It tells you the line number where the error actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting your user model from a different file and trying to import from a different file.

change this line:

```
 const User = require('../config/database');
```

to this:

```
 const User = require('../models/users')  # import your user model
```

Comment: i did what you said sir but another error is showing TypeError: bcrypt.gensalt is not a function i have edited post please check it again

Comment: `bcrypt.genSalt` is a function not `bcrypt.gensalt` refer [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#to-hash-a-password)

Comment: I would give you one more advice that stick to the problem statement you have posted initially don't ask a new problem by editing the question. Although posting another question would be much better.

Comment: after changes "home/deep/Desktop/project/meanauthapp/models/users.js:38
        if(err) throw err;
                ^

Error: data and salt arguments required" 
app is crashed now

Comment: we won't debug your whole application, stick to specific problems. We have already answered two of your problems in this question don't expect us to debug your whole code. Ask in chats if you are having a hard time grasping any of the concepts

Comment: break it to different question and then ask them it would be much better. Everyone here will help you but you have to follow some rules

Comment: Thanks so much i am new to stackoverflow community i will do according to rules